# Want to pass json array as django variable inside javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a json array and I want to pass this inside a javascript variable, inside the django template. I am able to access the variable inside django template `{{variable}}` . But not able to access this inside the javascript.This is my variable:

```
[
    
    {'Book ID': '1', 'Book Name': 'Challenging Times',
    
     'Category': 'Business', 'Price': '125.60'},
    
    {'Book ID': '2', 'Book Name': 'Learning JavaScript',
    
     'Category': 'Programming', 'Price': '56.00'}
    
]
```

I have used `{{variable|safe}}` inside the js but not working. Plz let me know where I am making the mistake.

Comment: Use  `json` module of python and it's two methods `json.loads()` and `json.dumps()`, and also in JavaScript there a module `JSON` and it's two methods `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`, to send and retrieve data in `string` datatype.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) template filter to add your variable to the template in a format that can be loaded in your JS

```
{{ variable|json_script:"foo" }}

<script>
    const foo = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('foo').textContent);
</script>
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: @Arun how is it not working, what error/issue are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error , the data what I am looking for is shown in the template via the js

Comment: @Arun it's not clear what your issue is, if you run `console.log(foo)` in your broswer's devtools console do you get the data you need?